# How to generate ground truth information using GPS data for SLAM system?

Tags: navigation, slam, gps

I'm interested in generating some datasets to evaluate system performance for SLAM.

I'm confused on how I can use the GPS information to generate absolute ground truth.

In particular what's confusing is how you address imprecise initial orientation information.

One approach I suppose is to evaluate relative offset between positions using an L2 metric as this ignores absolute orientation issues. How do the existing datasets generate this information?